# Regular Expression for percents (with % sign) in ASP.Net RegEx Validator

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I need a regex for the ASP.Net (4) Regex Validation control.  It needs to be a RegEx validator to support other dynamic behaviors outside the scope of this post..

I was using the following, but it fails if the user enters the % sign following the number (which is a req of my spec):

```
^(100(?:\.0{1,2})?|0*?\.\d{1,2}|\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$
```

I tried adding an atomic group of `^(?>%?)` at the end, with no luck, after reading the excellent post

[Regular expression greedy match not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413587/regular-expression-greedy-match-not-working-as-expected)

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
^(100(?:.0{1,2})?%?|0*?.\d{1,2}%?|\d{1,2}(?:.\d{1,2})?%?)$
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for numbers up to and including 100.00%!  I actually need to let in higher numbers, as 'percent of quota' is one possible metric which frequently exceeds 100%.  Sorry, I should have explained that!

Comment: this one accepts 22222 which is wrong .. you can test it here:http://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

try this one instead:

```
^0*(100(\.00?)?|[0-9]?[0-9](\.[0-9][0-9]?)?)%?$
```